# Scrape web pages using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have the following web page

```
</div><a href="https://www.emag.ro/laptop-lenovo-thinkbook-15-iil-cu-procesor-intel-core-i7-1065g7-pana-la-3-90-ghz-15-6-full-hd-16gb-512gb-ssd-intel-iris-plus-graphics-free-dos-mineral-grey-20sm003jrm/pd/DKBK1TMBM/#reviews-section" rel="nofollow" class="star-rating-container js-product-url" data-zone="reviews"><div class="star-rating star-rating-read rated-4.02  star-rating-sm  ">
        <div class="star-rating-inner " style="width: 100%"></div>
    </div><div class="star-rating-text ">
```

I want to extract the rating from this product.
For this product, the rating is defined here.

```
<div class="star-rating star-rating-read rated-4.02  star-rating-sm  ">
```

And i cannot extract **4.02.**

My code looks like :

```
rating = container.find_all(class_="star-rating star-rating-read rated")[0].text
```

I know that the above code is not ok, I was able to extract the price and name of the product but I can't extract the rating :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
rating = str(container.find_all(class_="star-rating")[0])
rindex = rating.index("rated")
print(rating[rindex+6:rindex+10])
```

Comment: it works but some products has after rating the word "stars" and if the rating in an integer the output will be sth like this 5 st or 4 st, if the rating is a float like 4,02 the output is great

Comment: Solved... score=rating[rindex+6:rindex+10].replace(' st', '')

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
import re

# regex extract the decimal digits from string
extract_ = re.compile(r"\d+.\d+") 

for div in container.find_all("div", attrs={"class": 'star-rating'}):
    for attr in div.attrs['class']:
        ratings_ = extract_.search(attr)

        if ratings_:
            print(ratings_.group())  # 4.02
```